# Equation to place points at a given radius producing inaccurate distances

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Created a circle of points, 50m, 100m, 150m and 200m from a central lat/lng (51.500421, -0.124754) using the sql functions below (one for the lat the other lng). I have adapted them from C# to sql and my math is not great. My concern is with the accuracy of the functions. The margin of error for some of the 200m points is near 0.75% (some points being >201.5m from the center point). I run the functions off of a lookup table in sql, which contains rows of the angles I want and the radius. Is there a more accurate equation than the ones I have?

[image]

```
Create function [dbo].[NewLatitude] (
    @Latitude float,
    @RadiusKm float,
    @Theta float
)
Returns float as
Begin

Declare @RadiusLon float,
        @RadiusLat float,
        @return_value float;

    Set @RadiusLat =  1 / 110.574 * @RadiusKm
    Set @return_value =  @Latitude + @RadiusLat * sin(@Theta)
 
    Return @return_value
End;
```

```
Create function [dbo].[NewLongitude] (
    @Latitude float,
    @Longitude float,
    @RadiusKm float,
    @Theta float
)
Returns float as
Begin

Declare @RadiusLon float,
        @RadiusLat float,
        @return_value float;

    Set @RadiusLon = (1 / (111.319 * cos(@Latitude * (pi() / 180))) * @radiusKm)
    Set @return_value =  @Longitude + @RadiusLon * cos(@Theta)
 
    Return @return_value
End;
```

Comment: Hey, didn't you JUST ask this? :)

Comment: Do you need to account for Earth curvature? The formulas assume that the Earth is flat which may be OK in your case. You are also using specific distances that correspond one degree of change in longitude or latitude, make sure those distances are correct for your starting point.